# Dieletric on Capacitors circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz, circuits

How can i fill the interior of a capacitor and label it using a greek letter in order to represent a dieletric inside the capacitor?

### My Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]

\begin{center}

\begin{circuitikz}

 \draw (0,0)

  to[battery1,v=$\epsilon$] (0,2) % The voltage source
  to[short] (2,2)
  to[C=$C_1$] (2,0) % The resistor
  to[short](4,0)
  to[C=$C_2$](4,2)
  to[short] (2,2);
  \draw(2,0)
  to[short](0,0);
  \end{circuitikz}
  \caption{My first circuit.}
  \end{center}
  end{figure}

  \end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. At the moment, your question is very short!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `name` key to give the element a name that can then be used to perform actions (for example, filling or adding labels) using some anchors:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{circuitikz}
  \draw (0,0)
    to[battery1,v=$\epsilon$] (0,2) % The voltage source
    to[short] (2,2)
    to[C=$C_1$,name=a] (2,0) % The resistor
    to[short](4,0)
    to[C=$C_2$,name=b](4,2)
    to[short] (2,2);
  \draw(2,0)
    to[short](0,0);
  \fill[fill=orange!40] 
    ([yshift=\pgflinewidth]a.se) 
      rectangle 
    ([yshift=-\pgflinewidth]a.nw);   
  \node at (a.center) {$\scriptstyle\alpha$};
  \fill[fill=cyan!40] 
    ([yshift=-\pgflinewidth]b.se) 
      rectangle 
    ([yshift=\pgflinewidth]b.nw);   
  \node[label={60:$\scriptstyle\beta$}] at (b.center) {};
\end{circuitikz}
\caption{My first circuit.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

### Remarks

- I changed the `center` environment to the `\centering` switch inside figure to avoid adding extra vertical space.
- `!h` as placement specifier for a float is a recipe for disaster; use a less restrictive option or, better yet, none at all.
- In the `circuitikz` implementation for bipoles, `se` is the chosen designation for the `south east` anchor, and `nw` is the one for the `north west` anchor. The shifts are needed to avoid the filling erasing half of the lines forming the capacitor.