# How to draw grid in background of electrical circuit

Tags: circuitikz

Even though I use the tikzlibrary backgrounds and declare a layer, bbg, that is behind the general created background layer I am still not able to draw a grid behind the circuit. The code below results in an unwanted overlap between the two drawings.

The code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\pgfdeclarelayer{bbg}
\pgfdeclarelayer{fg}
\pgfsetlayers{bbg,background,main,fg}    

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[european]

 \begin{pgfonlayer}{bbg}
  \foreach \x in {2,6,10,14,18} {
   \foreach \y in {-6,-2,2} {
    \draw[red] (\x,\y) -- (\x,\y +4);
    \draw[red] (\x,\y) -- (\x +4,\y);
    \draw[red] (\x,\y +4) -- (\x +4,\y +4);
    \draw[red] (\x +4,\y) -- (\x +4,\y +4);
   }
  }
 \end{pgfonlayer}

 \draw
  (0,0) 
   to[I=$I_{in}$,-*] (4,0)
  (4,0) 
   to[R=$R_{18}$,-*] (4,4)
   to[R=$R_{22}$,-*] (8,4)
   to[R=$R_{21}$,-*] (12,4)
   to[R=$R_{20}$,-*] (16,4)
   to[R=$R_{19}$,-*] (20,4)
  (4,0)
   to[R=$R_{13}$,-*] (8,0)
   to[R=$R_{12}$,-*] (12,0)
   to[R=$R_{11}$,-*] (16,0)
   to[R=$R_{10}$,-*] (20,0)
  (4,0)
   to[R, l_=$R_{09}$,-*] (4,-4)
   to[R=$R_{04}$,-*] (8,-4)
   to[R=$R_{03}$,-*] (12,-4)
   to[R=$R_{02}$,-*] (16,-4)
   to[R=$R_{01}$,-*] (20,-4)
  (8,0)
   to[R=$R_{17}$] (8,4)
  (8,0)   
   to[R, l_=$R_{08}$] (8,-4)
  (12,0)
   to[R=$R_{16}$] (12,4)
  (12,0) 
   to[R, l_=$R_{07}$] (12,-4) 
  (16,0)
   to[R=$R_{15}$] (16,4)
  (16,0)  
   to[R, l_=$R_{06}$] (16,-4)
  (20,0) 
   to[R=$R_{14}$] (20,4)
  (20,0) 
   to[R, l_=$R_{05}$] (20,-4)
  (20,4)
   to[R=$R_{24}$,-*] (22,4) 
  (20,-4)
   to[R=$R_{25}$,-*] (22,-4)
  (22,4)
   to[short] (22,-4)
   to[short] (22,-6)
   to[short] (9,-6)
   to[short] (0,-6)
   to[short] (0,0)  
  (9,0)
   to[R=$R_{23}$,*-] (9,-4)
   to[short,-*] (9,-6) 
   node[ground]{} 

  {
   [anchor=south east]
   (4,4) node {$N_{01}$}
   (4,0) node {$N_{02}$}
   (4,-4) node {$N_{03}$} 

   (8,4) node {$N_{04}$}
   (8,0) node {$N_{05}$}
   (8,-4) node {$N_{06}$}

   (12,4) node {$N_{07}$}
   (12,0) node {$N_{08}$}
   (12,-4) node {$N_{09}$}   

   (16,4) node {$N_{10}$}
   (16,0) node {$N_{11}$}
   (16,-4) node {$N_{12}$}

   (20,4) node {$N_{13}$}
   (20,0) node {$N_{14}$}
   (20,-4) node {$N_{15}$}  
  }      

 ;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! All red lines are below black lines and texts... What is your problem ?

Answer (score 2):

They do not overlap, the grid is in the background, but the resistor shapes are not filled. Replace one of them by a filled shape, e.g. write `fullgeneric=,...` instead of `R=...` and you will see the grid disappear behind the shape.

The circuitikz manual does not show an easy way to fill your shapes, otherwise you could have just filled the resistors with white colours. If you want to go this route anyway, you can have a look at [Dieletric on Capacitors circuitikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253429/dieletric-on-capacitors-circuitikz). Not having a possibility to easily fill the shapes is a clear disadvantage of circuitikz, with the native TikZ circuits library you are able to easily fill shapes. (Maybe I am wrong and there is an easy way that I was not able to discover.)

---

Disclaimer: some speculation follows:

I wonder if the reason behind this is a wrong understanding of technical correctness and standards. In my opinion, drawing circuits is a way to express technical facts, similar to using mathematical formulas. Whenever the state-of-the-art syntax is not enough to describe a fact, the syntax must have the possibility to be adapted (in math that always happens), and filling shapes is a very simple case.